# esp01_1m does not works after flashing

Tags: arduino, esp8266, platformio

I've tried to flash esp01_1m with code from [example](https://github.com/platformio/platform-espressif8266/tree/develop/examples/arduino-blink) with PlatformIO. Project compiles and flashes successfully, but after reset nothing happens.

platformio.ini

```
[env:esp01_1m]
platform = espressif8266
board = esp01_1m
upload_protocol = esptool
framework = arduino
```

I've tried to blink diode and/or write something into output (Serial), but nothing happens: no blinking and empty serial monitor.

I have 3 modules of esp01_1m but all of them has the same behavior.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is io 0 pulled-up?

Comment: @Juraj, yes. After flashing GP0 is up and in this state I'm unable to flash device. But nothing happens.
If I connect GP0 to GND I can reflash module after connect RST to GND.

Comment: yes, state of io 0 at boot selects between flashing mode and normal run.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was found solution. The problem was in low voltage (3,3 V). After switching to 5V, the module starts to work correct.